# How can I fixed squished/smaller website proportions?

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, shopify

I made an entire layout for a site using bootstrap in REPL, but when I moved all of my HTML, CSS, and whatnot, it appears way more squished on Shopify.

This is what I want: [image: repl]

This is what I get when I move to shopify: [image: shopify]

there's probably some stuff with bootstrap and shopify clashing in the background, so if you guys can give me some tips on achieving the desired layout WITHOUT using bootstrap, I would love that!

The bigger picture is making my shopify site look like this site: https://pharmacy.cargo.site/, so once again, if you can help, It would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the font the same?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, the lines are a lot more squished and in general everything looks worse.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.